# code to download a file locally from colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have to download a really large file (140 GB) from colab, which I created in colab, I tried downloading it manually by navigating to the files tab, but it is taking lots of time and getting failed. So, is there any other way or direct code through which I can download it to my pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

140 GB may be too big for Google Drive. So, you might try copying it to a GCS bucket first, then download from there.

Authenticate using `auth.athenticate_user()` first, then

```
!gsutil cp file.zip gs://your-bucket-name/
```

Then, download it through the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser).