# Tensorflow Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

I used Google Colab to train a model, and saved the weights as TensorFlow data set. Google Colab saved the weights as a folder. Now, I want to use this weight in another machine but it doesn't accept the folder as a TensorFlow vector. Is there any way to convert the folder to a single file or load the folder in different machine? I use Python 3.8 with TensorFlow 2.4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [code to download a file locally from colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674591/code-to-download-a-file-locally-from-colab)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can download it but it gives me a zip file containing the folder not a file.